# Wireless doesn't reconnect after resuming on after the upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 on my MacBook Pro.

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.04, suspend

I have a MacBook Pro with it dual-booting with Ubuntu 14.04 and Mac OS X, and a few days ago I upgraded Ubuntu from 13.10 to 14.04.  When I suspend and then resume the system, wireless tries to connect but fails, and I tried some solutions like restart the network or remove and reload the WiFi kernel module (b43), but nothing worked.  Only a restart of the system solve the issue.

The output of `dmesg` indicates an authentication problem:

```
...
[ 8050.906223] wlan0: deauthenticating from <mac_address> by local choice (reason=3)
[ 8050.914824] wlan0: authenticate with <mac_address>
[ 8050.915142] wlan0: send auth to <mac_address> (try 1/3)
[ 8050.917960] wlan0: authenticated
[ 8055.919691] wlan0: deauthenticating from <mac_address> by local choice (reason=3)
[ 8066.438256] wlan0: authenticate with <mac_address>
[ 8066.438631] wlan0: send auth to <mac_address> (try 1/3)
[ 8066.440185] wlan0: authenticated
[ 8071.447980] wlan0: deauthenticating from <mac_address> by local choice (reason=3)
[ 8082.466500] wlan0: authenticate with <mac_address>
[ 8082.473305] wlan0: send auth to <mac_address> (try 1/3)
[ 8082.493654] wlan0: authenticated
...
```

Comment: See bug [#1311257](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-nettool/+bug/1311257)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to restore connectivity, even though I did not understand what the cause of the problem.
However, killing the `wpa_supplicant` process, it will restart automatically, and the connection is restored:

```
sudo killall wpa_supplicant
```

output of dmesg:

```
[3481.457982] b43 bcma0: 0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM / QoS is not supported by the AP 
[3481.457992] b43 bcma0: 0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM / QoS is not supported by the AP 
[3481.461214] wlan0: associate with <mac_address> (try 1/3) 
[3481.464068] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <mac_address> (capab = 0x431 status = 0 aid = 3) 
[3481.464475] wlan0: associated 
[3481.464501] IPv6: ADDRCONF (NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link Becomes ready...
```

I hope it could be useful also to other.

Answer (score 3):

Create script /etc/pm/sleep.d/wpa_supplicant and the power management will automatically call "killall wpa_supplicant" when resumed.

/etc/pm/sleep.d/wpa_supplicant

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in
 resume)
   killall wpa_supplicant       
 ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution (on a Macbook Pro with Ubuntu 14.04) can be found in response to [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/710117/wireless-off-after-suspending/713837#713837)

In short, it is similar to what Joonas posted, but with some further modifications.