# Wireless off after suspending

Tags: 14.04, networking, suspend

From time to time, when I resume from `suspend` my computer, the networking won't work (happens on my laptop too, both running 14.04).
The wireless icon located in the corner looks like networking unable, and when I click on it, I get a very limited options menu.
One of the options is 'enable networking' but when I click on it, nothing happens (although it is checked).

I saw in other questions that the wireless-network card turns of when suspending and maybe it just won't turn on..
If this is the case, how to turn it on?

Comment: This is a bug and has not been resolved yet https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1286552

Comment: @TungTran the peculiar thing is that on my laptop if I suspend again and resume - the network goes back to normal (I mean, I don't need to actually restart the laptop)

Comment: Seems like this question is answered [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/452826/wireless-networking-not-working-after-resume-in-ubuntu-14-04?rq=1).

Comment: @TzahiLeh I also experience the same problem, I just suspend and resume after the initial resume... Also, if sufficient time is given for resume after initial suspend, my wireless driver was alright...

Answer (score 0):

Following the comments above suggestion linked by `Tzahi Leh` I have the following script saved as `/etc/pm/sleep.d/30_wakeup` and executable which seems to resolve the issue. Previous portions of the script existed and were taken from this [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1484156) for speaker and bluetooth issues known in Ubuntu 14.04, but it wasn't until a recent update that I had to add the `nmcli` line:

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in
suspend_hybrid|hibernate|suspend)
    # executed on suspend
    echo "Going to $1 at $(date)" >> /Data/sleep_log.txt
    rfkill block bluetooth
    ;;
thaw|resume) 
    # executed on resume
    # restart wireless, just in case
    restart network-manager > /dev/null
    # to resolve new issue, 27 Dec 2015 via: http://askubuntu.com/questions/452826/wireless-networking-not-working-after-resume-in-ubuntu-14-04?rq=1
    nmcli nm sleep false

    #wake up the speakers
    hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC1D0 0x1 set_gpio_mask 1
    sleep 1
    hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC1D0 0x1 set_gpio_direction 1
    sleep 1
    hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC1D0 0x1 set_gpio_data 1
    echo "waking up from $1 at $(date)" >> /Data/sleep_log.txt

    #bluetooth
    rfkill unblock bluetooth
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```